# The perfect rack for a pool variant called 'Cutthroat'

Tags: combinatorics

To give some background, the pool game 'Cutthroat' is played with three people, each person claiming the set of low balls (1-5), middle balls (6-10), or high balls (11-15). The goal of the game is to sink everyone else's balls, and to win by only having your own balls left on the table. (i.e. someone playing mid balls would sink all the low and high balls to win).

While racking up for a game, I was pondering whether or not it would be possible to have what I considered a 'perfect rack'. This would consist of there being only a single low, middle, and high ball in each 'sub-triangle' (triangle of only three balls) within the entire triangular rack. Is this possible to do?

Also, as I'm not the most mathematically educated, I feel it's worth noting that I'm not 100% sure what to classify this problem as, so I went with combinatorics. If someone would also like to share what field of mathematics this falls under I would appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of configuration you are looking for ?
[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for. How would one go about proving this mathematically, or otherwise generally showing that it is possible? edit: also i apologize if I did not explain myself well in the original post

Comment: Once you have chosen the top three, everything else will be forced.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Is there a mathematical/notational way of showing that?